# Magento2 fetch value from catalog_compare_item table

Tags: magento2, database, table, compare

Magento2 How can I get the value of following table 'catalog_compare_item' using a model or any other proper way of Magento?

Comment: which information you are going to take?

Comment: customer id & product id